# detect fuzzy pattern matches on analog input device

Tags: design-patterns, audio, input, wave

Sometime in 2003 I had a linux program that would constantly sample the sound card's analog microphone input.  It had a database of samples pre-loaded and it could detect similar patterns in the input stream.  This program allowed arbitrary commands to be called on each positive match.  Irrelevant to this question, I hooked mine into an x10 bottlerocket interface and subsequently acquired sound control of my house's lighting.  But it was not at all a speech to text program.  It was a dumb, fuzzy match.  I could have trained it with some pots being clanged together.

I'm tossing my line far out into the sea, since I suspect this will be a fringe expertise answer.

Edit: Indeed, I neglected to ask a question.

Question - does anyone know of such a program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application you described sounds a lot like [CVoiceControl](http://www.kiecza.net/daniel/linux/). From the looks of the site, the project is no longer maintained.

There's also [GnomeVoiceControl](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeVoiceControl), but it does seem like the actions it can trigger are limited to desktop operations.

*Disclaimer: I have tried neither.*

Comment: I really feel like CVoiceControl might just be it.  Thanks!